# Showing tellraw message but no scoreboard messages in chat (CommandBlock)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have three following up commandblocks and an armorstand:
Repeating one, unconditional, always active:
`scoreboard players add @e[type=armor_stand,r=5,score_time_min=1] time 1`

Chained one, unconditional, always active:
`tp @e[type=armor_stand,r=5,score_time_min=72001] ~ ~1 ~ tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Hello guys please read the server rules! Click on this message for them..","color":"gold","bold":true,"underlined":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/rules"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":"You are ruling!"}}]`

Chained one, conditional, always active:
`scoreboard players set @e[score_time_min=201] time 1`

Therefore this is a timer, but at the end of the timer it should do the tellraw command and it does not. It does the counting correctly, but it does not show the tellraw command in chat. I want exactly the opposite.

I have already checked if a gamerule was disabled, this was not the case.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you using minecraft Java Edition? If so, version 1.12 or 1.13?

Comment: Are you playing with mods? `/rules` is no Vanilla command.

Comment: I am using 1.12 and standard mod pack (Forge and Liteloader) with Forge Essentials. Sorry for not telling that..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` to disable for example messages when teleporting, but keep `/tellraw`, `/say`, etc. messages.

Comment: When using that gamerule it doesn't show my tellraw message. Have I accidentally edited one gamerule which makes this happen? It also does not happen when commandBlockOutput is true.

Comment: I think it's sendCommandFeedback

Comment: Thanks! I have completed the timed messages with four commandblocks!

Answer (score 0):

Four commandblocks and an armorstand: Repeating one, unconditional, always active: scoreboard players add @e[type=armor_stand,r=5,score_time_min=1] time 1

Chained one, unconditional, always active: tp @e[type=armor_stand,r=5,score_time_min=72001] ~ ~1 ~ tellraw

Chained one, conditional, always active: scoreboard players set @e[score_time_min=201] time 1

Chained one, conditional, always active: tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Hello guys please read the server rules! Click on this message for them..","color":"gold","bold":true,"underlined":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/rules"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":"You are ruling!"}}]

The second commandblock needs the tellraw!!